# Package conflicts during r-seurat installation

Tags: conda

Now I am trying to install r-seurat from bioconda, but package conflicts shown during installation as following:

```
Package libcxxabi conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> libcxx[version='>=4.0.1'] -> libcxxabi==4.0.1[build='hcfea43d_1|hebd6815_0']
r-seurat -> libcxx[version='>=4.0.1'] -> libcxxabi==4.0.1[build='hcfea43d_1|hebd6815_0']

Package ncurses conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> readline[version='>=7.0,<8.0a0'] -> ncurses[version='6.0.*|>=6.0,<7.0a0']
python=3.7 -> ncurses[version='>=6.1,<7.0a0']

(anndata) Ilkyunui-MacBookPro-3:20200210 ilkyun$ conda list
# packages in environment at /anaconda3/envs/anndata:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_r-mutex                  1.0.0               anacondar_1
anndata                   0.7.1                    pypi_0    pypi
anndata2ri                1.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
appnope                   0.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
attrs                     19.3.0                     py_0
backcall                  0.1.0                    py37_0
bleach                    3.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
bwidget                   1.9.11                        1
bzip2                     1.0.8                h1de35cc_0
ca-certificates           2020.1.1                      0
cairo                     1.14.12              hc4e6be7_4
cctools                   895                           1
certifi                   2019.11.28               py37_0
cffi                      1.13.2                   pypi_0    pypi
clang                     4.0.1                         1
clang_osx-64              4.0.1               h1ce6c1d_18
clangxx                   4.0.1                         1
clangxx_osx-64            4.0.1               h22b1bf0_18
compiler-rt               4.0.1                hcfea43d_1
curl                      7.67.0               ha441bb4_0
cycler                    0.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
dbus                      1.13.12              h90a0687_0
decorator                 4.4.2                      py_0
defusedxml                0.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
entrypoints               0.3                      pypi_0    pypi
expat                     2.2.6                h0a44026_0
fontconfig                2.13.0               h5d5b041_1
freetype                  2.9.1                hb4e5f40_0
fribidi                   1.0.5                h1de35cc_0
get-version               2.1                      pypi_0    pypi
gettext                   0.19.8.1             h15daf44_3
gfortran_osx-64           4.8.5                h22b1bf0_8
glib                      2.63.1               hd977a24_0
graphite2                 1.3.13               h2098e52_0
gsl                       2.4                  h1de35cc_4
h5py                      2.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
harfbuzz                  1.8.8                hb8d4a28_0
icu                       58.2                 h4b95b61_1
importlib-metadata        1.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
importlib_metadata        1.5.0                    py37_0
ipykernel                 5.1.4            py37h39e3cac_0
ipython                   7.13.0           py37h5ca1d4c_0
ipython-genutils          0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py37_0
ipywidgets                7.5.1                      py_0
jedi                      0.16.0                   py37_0
jinja2                    2.10.3                   pypi_0    pypi
joblib                    0.14.1                   pypi_0    pypi
jpeg                      9b                   he5867d9_2
jsonschema                3.2.0                    py37_0
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py37_7
jupyter-client            6.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-core              4.6.3                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter_client            5.3.4                    py37_0
jupyter_console           6.1.0                      py_0
jupyter_core              4.6.1                    py37_0
kiwisolver                1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
krb5                      1.16.4               hddcf347_0
ld64                      274.2                         1
legacy-api-wrap           1.2                      pypi_0    pypi
libcurl                   7.67.0               h051b688_0
libcxx                    4.0.1                hcfea43d_1
libcxxabi                 4.0.1                hcfea43d_1
libedit                   3.1.20181209         hb402a30_0
libffi                    3.2.1                h475c297_4
libgfortran               3.0.1                h93005f0_2
libiconv                  1.15                 hdd342a3_7
libpng                    1.6.37               ha441bb4_0
libsodium                 1.0.16               h3efe00b_0
libssh2                   1.9.0                ha12b0ac_1
libtiff                   4.1.0                hcb84e12_0
libxml2                   2.9.9                hf6e021a_1
llvm                      4.0.1                         1
llvm-lto-tapi             4.0.1                         1
llvm-openmp               4.0.1                hcfea43d_1
llvmlite                  0.31.0                   pypi_0    pypi
make                      4.2.1                h3efe00b_1
markupsafe                1.1.1            py37h1de35cc_0
matplotlib                3.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
mistune                   0.8.4            py37h1de35cc_0
more-itertools            8.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
natsort                   7.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
nbconvert                 5.6.1                    py37_0
nbformat                  5.0.4                      py_0
ncurses                   6.2                  h0a44026_0
notebook                  6.0.3                    py37_0
numba                     0.48.0                   pypi_0    pypi
numexpr                   2.7.1                    pypi_0    pypi
openssl                   1.1.1d               h1de35cc_4
packaging                 20.0                     pypi_0    pypi
pandas                    0.25.3                   pypi_0    pypi
pandoc                    2.2.3.2                       0
pandocfilters             1.4.2                    py37_1
pango                     1.42.4               h060686c_0
parso                     0.6.2                    pypi_0    pypi
patsy                     0.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pcre                      8.43                 h0a44026_0
pexpect                   4.8.0                    py37_0
pickleshare               0.7.5                    pypi_0    pypi
pip                       20.0.2                   py37_1
pixman                    0.38.0               h1de35cc_0
pluggy                    0.13.1                   pypi_0    pypi
prometheus_client         0.7.1                      py_0
prompt-toolkit            3.0.4                    pypi_0    pypi
prompt_toolkit            3.0.3                      py_0
ptyprocess                0.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
py                        1.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pycparser                 2.19                     pypi_0    pypi
pygments                  2.6.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pyparsing                 2.4.6                    pypi_0    pypi
pyqt                      5.9.2            py37h655552a_2
pyrsistent                0.15.7           py37h1de35cc_0
pytest                    5.3.2                    pypi_0    pypi
python                    3.7.6                h359304d_2
python-dateutil           2.8.1                      py_0
pytz                      2019.3                   pypi_0    pypi
pyzmq                     19.0.0                   pypi_0    pypi
qt                        5.9.7                h468cd18_1
qtconsole                 4.7.1                      py_0
qtpy                      1.9.0                      py_0
r-assertthat              0.2.1             r36h6115d3f_0
r-base                    3.6.1                hcb44179_1
r-base64enc               0.1_3             r36h46e59ec_4
r-bh                      1.69.0_1          r36h6115d3f_0
r-caret                   6.0_83            r36h46e59ec_0
r-class                   7.3_15            r36h46e59ec_0
r-cli                     1.1.0             r36h6115d3f_0
r-codetools               0.2_16            r36h6115d3f_0
r-colorspace              1.4_1             r36h46e59ec_0
r-crayon                  1.3.4             r36h6115d3f_0
r-curl                    3.3               r36h46e59ec_0
r-data.table              1.12.2            r36h46e59ec_0
r-dichromat               2.0_0             r36h6115d3f_4
r-digest                  0.6.18            r36h46e59ec_0
r-dplyr                   0.8.0.1           r36h466af19_0
r-essentials              1.0                          0a
r-evaluate                0.13              r36h6115d3f_0
r-fansi                   0.4.0             r36h46e59ec_0
r-foreach                 1.4.4             r36h6115d3f_0
r-generics                0.0.2             r36h6115d3f_0
r-ggplot2                 3.1.1             r36h6115d3f_0
r-glmnet                  2.0_16            r36hfffe0aa_0
r-glue                    1.3.1             r36h46e59ec_0
r-gower                   0.2.0             r36h46e59ec_0
r-gtable                  0.3.0             r36h6115d3f_0
r-highr                   0.8               r36h6115d3f_0
r-htmltools               0.3.6             r36h466af19_0
r-httpuv                  1.5.1             r36h466af19_0
r-ipred                   0.9_8             r36h46e59ec_0
r-iterators               1.0.10            r36h6115d3f_0
r-jsonlite                1.6               r36h46e59ec_0
r-kernsmooth              2.23_15           r36hfffe0aa_4
r-knitr                   1.22              r36h6115d3f_0
r-labeling                0.3               r36h6115d3f_4
r-later                   0.8.0             r36h466af19_0
r-lattice                 0.20_38           r36h46e59ec_0
r-lava                    1.6.5             r36h6115d3f_0
r-lazyeval                0.2.2             r36h46e59ec_0
r-lubridate               1.7.4             r36h466af19_0
r-magrittr                1.5               r36h6115d3f_4
r-markdown                0.9               r36h46e59ec_0
r-mass                    7.3_51.3          r36h46e59ec_0
r-matrix                  1.2_17            r36h46e59ec_0
r-mgcv                    1.8_28            r36h46e59ec_0
r-mime                    0.6               r36h46e59ec_0
r-modelmetrics            1.2.2             r36h466af19_0
r-munsell                 0.5.0             r36h6115d3f_0
r-nlme                    3.1_139           r36hfffe0aa_0
r-nnet                    7.3_12            r36h46e59ec_0
r-numderiv                2016.8_1          r36h6115d3f_0
r-pillar                  1.3.1             r36h6115d3f_0
r-pkgconfig               2.0.2             r36h6115d3f_0
r-plogr                   0.2.0             r36h6115d3f_0
r-plyr                    1.8.4             r36h466af19_0
r-prodlim                 2018.04.18        r36h466af19_0
r-promises                1.0.1             r36h466af19_0
r-purrr                   0.3.2             r36h46e59ec_0
r-quantmod                0.4_14            r36h6115d3f_0
r-r6                      2.4.0             r36h6115d3f_0
r-randomforest            4.6_14            r36hfffe0aa_0
r-rcolorbrewer            1.1_2             r36h6115d3f_0
r-rcpp                    1.0.1             r36h466af19_0
r-rcpproll                0.3.0             r36h466af19_0
r-recipes                 0.1.5             r36h6115d3f_0
r-reshape2                1.4.3             r36h466af19_0
r-rlang                   0.3.4             r36h46e59ec_0
r-rmarkdown               1.12              r36h6115d3f_0
r-rpart                   4.1_15            r36h46e59ec_0
r-scales                  1.0.0             r36h466af19_0
r-shiny                   1.3.2             r36h6115d3f_0
r-sourcetools             0.1.7             r36h466af19_0
r-squarem                 2017.10_1         r36h6115d3f_0
r-stringi                 1.4.3             r36h466af19_0
r-stringr                 1.4.0             r36h6115d3f_0
r-survival                2.44_1.1          r36h46e59ec_0
r-tibble                  2.1.1             r36h46e59ec_0
r-tidyr                   0.8.3             r36h466af19_0
r-tidyselect              0.2.5             r36h466af19_0
r-timedate                3043.102          r36h6115d3f_0
r-tinytex                 0.12              r36h6115d3f_0
r-ttr                     0.23_4            r36hfffe0aa_0
r-utf8                    1.1.4             r36h46e59ec_0
r-viridislite             0.3.0             r36h6115d3f_0
r-withr                   2.1.2             r36h6115d3f_0
r-xfun                    0.6               r36h6115d3f_0
r-xtable                  1.8_4             r36h6115d3f_0
r-xts                     0.11_2            r36h46e59ec_0
r-yaml                    2.2.0             r36h46e59ec_0
r-zoo                     1.8_6             r36h46e59ec_0
readline                  7.0                  h1de35cc_5
rpy2                      3.2.6                    pypi_0    pypi
scanpy                    1.4.5.1                  pypi_0    pypi
scikit-learn              0.22.2.post1             pypi_0    pypi
scipy                     1.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
seaborn                   0.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
send2trash                1.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
setuptools                46.0.0                   py37_0
setuptools-scm            3.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
sip                       4.19.8           py37h0a44026_0
six                       1.13.0                   pypi_0    pypi
sqlite                    3.31.1               ha441bb4_0
statsmodels               0.11.1                   pypi_0    pypi
tables                    3.6.1                    pypi_0    pypi
terminado                 0.8.3                    pypi_0    pypi
testpath                  0.4.4                      py_0
tk                        8.6.8                ha441bb4_0
tktable                   2.10                 h1de35cc_0
tornado                   6.0.4            py37h1de35cc_1
tqdm                      4.43.0                   pypi_0    pypi
traitlets                 4.3.3                    py37_0
tzlocal                   2.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
umap-learn                0.3.10                   pypi_0    pypi
wcwidth                   0.1.8                      py_0
webencodings              0.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
wheel                     0.34.2                   py37_0
widgetsnbextension        3.5.1                    py37_0
xz                        5.2.4                h1de35cc_4
zeromq                    4.3.1                h0a44026_3
zipp                      0.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
zlib                      1.2.11               h1de35cc_3
zstd                      1.3.7                h5bba6e5_0
```

I can't understand why these conflicts occur because I think that the versions of the packages met the requirements.

There is no conflict when I install r-seurat=3.1.4 from conda-forge, but I need r-seurat=3.0.2 from bioconda because an issue in jupyter notebook.

Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, the package conflict reports are buggy and usually unhelpful. Unfortunately, there's not really a way for us to troubleshoot this for you. My best guess is conflicts with the PyPI packages. Perhaps try enabling Pip interoperability for this env: 1) activate it, then 2) `conda config --env --set pip_interop_enabled True`.  Otherwise, just make a new env - that's what Conda is designed for; installing packages *ad hoc* in a monolithic env is bad practice.